# openssl dynamic debug library linking

Tags: c++, dll, linker, openssl

I downloaded openssl library and there is only one dynamic (DLL) library and multiple (.lib) files with MD and MDd.

And my question is: where is dynamic (DLL) **debug** library?

Is it possible that there is **one DLL** per **debug** and **nondebug** version?

Comment: DLL is dynamic link library, if you want to debug ddl try finding the associated pdb files.

Answer (score 0):

> where is dynamic (DLL) debug library?

What made you believe there should be one?

It is quite possible that the developer didn't build the debug DLL, because he is not expecting that there will be many processes that are simultaneously using the debug variant (and thus having a DLL provides no benefit). If so, all the code is in the `.lib`, and that's *all* you need.

It's also possible that the developer made a packaging mistake, and forgot to include the DLL in whatever package you've downloaded.